# CSS Url property on sites?

Tags: css

I like to sometimes try to "reverse engineer" websites, particularly ones that look complex. I feel in doing so it will help me learn techniques that other developers use.

I recently wanted to look at the league of legends website. The first thing I tried was to see how they placed their site's head/nav image. I use firefox so I used the "right-click -> inspect" function. In doing so I found this

```
<html>..........
<body class="not-front not-logged-in page-node node-type-lc-article no-sidebars i18n-en pvpnetbar">
    <style> … </style>
        <div id="lol-header" class="i18n-en" role="banner">
            <div class="section clearfix">
                <div id="lol-header-sitename">
                    <a id="site-name" class="hidden-text" alt="Home" rel="home" title="Home" href="http://na.leagueoflegends.com/"> … </a>
                </div>
......</html>
```

the div that has a CSS Url property is 'lol-header' and it's value is

```
url("../img/lol-header-sprite.png")
```

I know that anytime you see two dots before a forward slash that it means you go to the parent directory. Now, I can see if the url was "http://na.leagueoflegends.com/learn/new_user_guide' then the relative url should be http://na.leagueoflegends.com/img/lol-header-sprite.png" ...but this doesn't work. Also, if you are on the main page it has the same relative URL.

How can that be? I thought I knew a good amount about web coding, but I'm kind of lost :-\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you're referring to loads the CSS files like this:

```
@import url('/sites/default/files/lol_global_elements/css/lol_global_elements.css');
```

The CSS rule itself is:

```
background: transparent url(../img/lol-header-sprite.png) 50% 0px no-repeat;
```

The `../` means go up one level, relative to the path the file was loaded from. So taking the first URL, it would begin with:

```
http://na.leagueoflegends.com/sites/default/files/lol_global_elements/
```

Then it adds `img/lol-header-sprite.png` to give you:

```
http://na.leagueoflegends.com/sites/default/files/lol_global_elements/img/lol-header-sprite.png
```

Comment: Where'd you find the lol_global_elements.CSS? I didn't find it referenced in the HTML file. I saw that CSS file name while I was inspecting elements though, but I didn't know where to find it.

Comment: Line 29 in the source at na.leagueoflegends.com

Comment: D'oh, thanks! I completely missed that. When I clicked lol_global_elements reference in the inspect tool, it opened the html document to line 35. Thanks a bunch! You've been very helpful

Answer (score 2):

The img location is relative to the location of the *CSS* file that includes the styling for this div.

As you can see the css file is:

```
http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/sites/default/files/lol_global_elements/css/lol_global_elements.css
```

which means , that the image is here:

```
 http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/sites/default/files/lol_global_elements/img/lol-header-sprite.png
```

`../img` of `/css` folder is `lol_global_elements/img`

Answer (score 0):

Use an Absolute URL, relative to the site:

```
url("/img/lol-header-sprite.png")
```

Always, it refers to `http://na.leagueoflegends.com/img/lol-header-sprite.png`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
url("/img/lol-header-sprite.png")
```